# Espacio en content

Tags: html

Tengo mi pagina web, pero como puedo hacerle para que abarque todo el ancho de esta, ya que me aparece de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<body style="padding:0px;">
    <div class="container body-content" style="margin:0px">
       //contenido
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `width:100vw` ?

Comment: `<body style="width:100%">` no te funciona?